# What is a faucet base ring for?

Tags: faucet

Does anyone know what is the use of the base ring under a faucet? https://www.amazon.com.au/Kitchen-Faucet-Rosette-Chromed-Plastic/dp/B07FNQ97P2

I've picked up a used tap, but it doesn't have a base ring on it:

[image]

Should I get a base ring or is it a purely aesthetic component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meant to provide a neat, clean mounting for the faucet. It also has a washer to prevent leaking into the cabinet below. If your faucet fits snugly into the hole on your sink, you can seal it with a small bead of caulk and you won't need the base ring. If the sink hole is a bit larger, then you'll need the base ring to act as a reducer for the faucet. Not sure if the base ring in your picture is, in fact, the base ring for your faucet.

Comment: Instead of caulk around the outside, plumber's putty underneath the trim ring (either one designed specifically for the faucet or a generic replacement) will make a watertight seal and _not_ be difficult to remove down the road.

Comment: I would consider a rubber o-ring (or even flat washer) between the faucet base (where the tip of your finger is) and countertop superior to plumber's putty. It can't be that hard to find one in the right size.